# How to get max value from row and column header in sql?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to extract the values and column header of an ID column from the rows containing the maximum values of each of several other columns and create a simple table with ID column, name, max(value) and column header of max(value).

Table looks like this. Roughly 160MM rows x 50 columns

```
 id | name  | A | B | C | D | E | ... 
----+-------+---+---+---+---+---+----
101 | name1 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 3 | ... 
102 | name2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 2 | ... 
103 | name3 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 1 | ... 
104 | name4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 6 | ... 
... | ..... | . | . | . | . | . | ...
```

I expect the query output to be as below:

```
 id | name  | max(value)  | col_name of max(value)|
----+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
101 | name1 | 5           | B                     |
102 | name2 | 4           | D                     |
103 | name3 | 5           | B                     | 
104 | name4 | 6           | E                     |
... | ..... | .           | .                     |
```

I'm using this code:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE xx AS (
SELECT id, name,
   MAX(col) AS max(value),
   col_name AS col_name of max(value)
FROM (
SELECT id, name, A AS col, 'A' col_name FROM table
UNION
SELECT id, name, B , 'B' col_name FROM table
UNION
...)
GROUP BY id,name,
     col_name
```

However I'm getting duplicate values (~166MM increased to ~800MM rows) and exponential increase in processing time. I have tried multiple solution from google/stack overflow, but none of them help solve this.

Any guidance or suggestion will really help.

Regards,
Shri

Comment: If you do not aggregate ID somehow then all rows will be duplicated: the number of distinct ID x number of columns. Consider removing ID column or aggregating somehow like taking id from record with max column value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `greatest` as follows:

```
select id, name, 
       greatest(a,b,c,d,e) as max_val,
       case greatest(a,b,c,d,e) 
            when a then 'A' when b then 'B' when c then 'C' when d then 'D'
       end as col_name_max
  from your_table
```

Comment: @Shri . . . Just as a note:  this won't work if any of the values are `NULL`.  If that is an issue, ask a *new* question.

Comment: thank you for the call out. However my data does not have any null values. Hence should work